# sap.ui.core.util.Export with German Umlauts

Tags: excel, csv, save, export, sapui5

I am trying to export data in SAPUI5 with sap.ui.core.util.Export and sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV:

```
var oExport2 = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({
      exportType : new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({
           separatorChar : ";",
           charset : "utf-8",
      }),
      models : oModel,
      rows : {
           path : '/',
      },
      columns : [
           {
           template : {
            content : {
                path : "Title"
                      }
           }
      },
      ]
});
```

and

```
console.log(oExport2);
oExport2.saveFile().always(function() {
                    this.destroy();
                  });
```

The thing is, before .saveFile() every Umlaut is still displayed correctly e.g. when logging before saveFile() -- all umlauts shown. Also in the oModel and my JSON data, every Umlaut correct.

But in my Excel, received from saveFile() all Umlauts are not shown correctly, some characters like "berÃ¼cksichtigt" are shown (should be "ü"). Thanks!!!

What can I do?? charset in util.Export does not seem to work.. any hint would be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot really reproduce your issue. Have you set the charset of the html-page to utf-8 (either via header or meta-tag in the html-head)?

This seems to work, could you please test:
http://jsbin.com/kubomipomi/1/edit?html,output